# undefined object in map collection javascript

Tags: javascript, collections, dictionary, undefined

I have my custom class and I want to store it into map collection, but while I want to get one of the value from the map (one instance of my object) I got error that object is undefined. Is there any possibility to cast object or something? If I push simple string instead of object of my custom class everything is ok. Someone can tell me how to solve this problem? Of course if this problem could be solved.

js:

```
function CustomClass(first, second, third){
    this.one = first;
    this.two = second;
    this.three = third;
}

CustomClass.prototype.constains(obj1, obj2){}

...
var dictionary = new Object();
dictionary[key] = CustomClass(1, "lel", 2);
for(var el in dictionary) //here IE debugger shows that I have a right key, but the value is undefined.
{
    if(dictionary[el].contains(something))
    {...}
}
```

If it depends I use IE10. Thanks for help and also for tips!

## edit:

If I use

```
dictionary[key] = new CustomClass(1, "lel", 2);
```

instead of:

```
dictionary[key] = CustomClass(1, "lel", 2);
```

it works, but someone could tell me why, something like this:

```
dictionary[key] = "lel";
```

works without new operator? From what I know everything in js is an object so what's the difference beetwen inserting a string and a custom class? (I'm new in js, so sorry for my bad knowledge)

Comment: Your syntax is not right, you didn't use `new` to call `CustomClass`, can you post a demo to reproduce the issue? Try http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `var elem[key] = ` doesn’t look right

Comment: @elclanrs wow, Thank You for a very fast answer, if I add a new it works :)
var elem[key] = new CustomClass(1, "lel", 2);
 instead of var elem[key] = CustomClass(1, "lel", 2);

But can You tell me why, something like this:
var elem[key] = "lel"; works without new operator? From what I know everything in js is an object so what's the difference beetwen inserting a string and a custom class? (I'm new in js, so sorry for my bad knowledge)

Comment: what is `elem`?  You haven't declared that.  Also, as David says, you shouldn't use `var` in front of `elem[key] = `

Comment: @Alnitak sorry I didn't noticed that I fix that. It should be dictionary[key] = ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already learned, in JS objects are constructed with functions, but the `new` keyword is critical.

When you do `var foo = new Bar()` the interpreter not only creates a new object and sets it to `this` within that constructor, that object is also then the implicit return value of the constructor.

If you omit `new` then within `Bar` the `this` context will will be the default (`undefined` in ES5 strict mode, or the global object - typically `window` otherwise), and the non-existent return value of the function (i.e. `undefined`) will be assigned to `foo`.

It is possible to turn a plain function into an "automatic constructor" that doesn't neeed the `new` keyword like this:

```
function Bar(x, y, z) {
    if (!(this instanceof Bar)) {
        return new Bar(x, y, z);
    }

    ...
}
```

i.e. the function can figure out that it wasn't invoked with `new`, so immediately just calls itself with `new` instead.